# How do I use dhclient to determine if the DHCP server can provide DNS servers?

Tags: dns, dhcp

OS is Debian 10-12. I know in some (most?) cases, a DHCP server will provide DNS servers at the same time as it leases an ip address.

I would like to use dhclient to get a list of DNS servers provided by the DHCP server.

(I realize I can look in /var/lib/dhcp for a lease file, but I want to do an active query in order to check the current state of the DHCP server.)

Comment: dhclient works by receiving information from the DHCP server and then calling out to script (by default `/sbin/dhclient-script`) to make the necessary changes on your system. You can write your own script to replace the default `dhclient-script` and do whatever you want with that information (`dhclient -sf /path/to/my/script`).

Comment: Is there a way to just print the data to stdout without modifying my system?

Comment: You don't need to "modify your system". You just need to create a new script file (possibly a temporary file you create as part of a larger shell script).

Comment: Gotcha, I just want to be sure I don't interfere with the normal operation of dhclient while using a system to test the dhcp server